# how to bind Application controller property in another controller ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-components, ember-controllers

i have search property in ApplicationController and its linked with input field of searching.
i want to access search field of ApplicationController in ProjectController. it should be sync.
i use following code but its not working.

/ app/controllers/projects/index.js  (project Controller)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    searchBinding: 'controllers.application.search'
});
```

/ app/controllers/application.js  (Application Controller)

```
  import Ember from 'ember';
    export default Ember.Controller.extend({
      search: ''
    )}
```

application.hbs

`{{input value = search}`}

Comment: What ember version do you use? `needs` and bindings are deprecated in current ember versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access any controller within controller by inject it.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    applicationController: Ember.inject.controller('application'),
    searchProperty: Ember.computed.alias('applicationController.search'),
)};
```

[Managing Dependences between Ember controllers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/)

Comment: Now it's `import { inject } from '@ember/controller'; /*...*/ applicationController: inject('application')`

Answer (score 15):

Ember needs is deprecated and is now used differently.

It works like this:

```
applicationController: Ember.inject.controller('application'),
mySearch: Ember.computed.alias('applicationController.search')
```

In your hbs template -

```
{{mySearch}}
```

is in sync with applications property "search".

Comment: **needs: ['Controller Name']** has been deprecated? why i was not able to access application controller with **needs:['Controller Name ']** technique?

Comment: Yes it's deprecated, was used in old Ember.

Answer (score 1):

You can access controllers properties included with `needs` this way :

```
{{controllers.neededController.property}}
```

In you case try :

```
{{input value=controllers.application.search}}
```

See example here : http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/

Comment: You are right, the method I show is deprecated. I added a jsfiddle example in case someone needed a solution for an older version of Ember but your answer is definitely better.